# DHT Sensor Python script error

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, sensors

I have a sensor type DHT22 connected to a raspberry.
I have written a script in python but when I run it I get errors

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import MySQLdb
import subprocess
import re
import sys
import time
import datetime
import Adafruit_DHT

conn = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","zeus","gee3g673r","logi")
while(True):
date = time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
clock = time.strftime("%H:%M")

#output = subprocess.check_output(["/usr/bin/AdafruitDHT.py 2302", "4"]);
output = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(Adafruit_DHT.AM2302, 4)
matches = re.search("Temp =\s+([0-9.]+)", output)
 if (not matches):
 time.sleep(0)
 continue
temp = float(matches.group(1))

matches = re.search("Hum =\s+([0-9.]+)", output)
 if (not matches):
 time.sleep(0)
 continue
humidity = float(matches.group(1))

# MYSQL DATA Processing
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("INSERT INTO data_th (date, clock, temp, hum) VALUES (%s, %s,%s, %s)",(date, clock, temp, humidity))

#print "DB Loaded"

time.sleep(360)
```

This is the error encountered on running the script:

```
root@raspberrypi:/home# ./hdt.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./dht.py", line 22, in <module>
matches = re.search("Temp =\s+([0-9.]+)", output)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 142, in search
return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Comment: The only thing I noticed is you do your regex in a string. I usually use the raw string method like this: `searchObj = re.search( r'(.*) are (.*?) .*', line, re.M|re.I)`

Comment: Your `output` probably isn't the right type.  Can you force it to string?  `repr(output)`?

Answer (score 0):

Adafruit_DHT.read_retry() does not return string. re.search expects string as second parameter.

Please have a look at code below (taken from [Adafruit_Python_DHT/examples](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_DHT/blob/master/examples/AdafruitDHT.py)):

```
# Try to grab a sensor reading.  Use the read_retry method which will retry up
# to 15 times to get a sensor reading (waiting 2 seconds between each retry).
humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(sensor, pin)

# Un-comment the line below to convert the temperature to Fahrenheit.
# temperature = temperature * 9/5.0 + 32

# Note that sometimes you won't get a reading and
# the results will be null (because Linux can't
# guarantee the timing of calls to read the sensor).  
# If this happens try again!
if humidity is not None and temperature is not None:
    print 'Temp={0:0.1f}*  Humidity={1:0.1f}%'.format(temperature, humidity)
else:
    print 'Failed to get reading. Try again!'
    sys.exit(1)
```